# It's embarrassing <?> the extremes he'll go to in order to impress his boss

Tags: punctuation

> [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/extreme_2#extreme_idmg_1):
>
> *It's embarrassing the extremes he'll go to in order to impress his boss*.

Why is this sentence correct without any punctuation after "*it's embarrassing*", e.g. a dash?

Thanks!

Comment: The sentence is, however, ambiguous and punctuation would be better because it could seem like the extremes are being embarrassed.

Comment: Modelling on _They're embarassing – those stains on my shirt._ one would certainly expect _some_ sort of punctuation there. But the whole sentence seems not unidiomatic, but certainly extra-grammatical. A Google search shows examples with and without the comma. I'd probably use the dash (which covers a multitude of sins) and claim sentence-fragment-guilt immunity. But I concede that the zero-punctuation fans here have cadence on their side (there need be no pause in speaking).

Comment: The "right" thing to do would be to separate the two pieces with a comma, dash, or even a colon.  But, even though the syntax is not literally correct without punctuation, it's not unusual to see punctuation omitted in such cases.

Comment: You can punctuate it or not. If I were to punctuate it, I would use a colon. It could also be rephrased: ***What's*** *embarrassing **is** the extremes …*

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any needed break in the sentence; an equivalent sentence might be :

> It's embarrassing how far he goes in order to impress his boss.

Which won't use any dash or comma either.

Comment: Hello, Nathaniel. Good answers on ELU are expected to have supporting references for what is claimed to be acceptable usage; answers lacking them come across as (and have sometimes been found to be) misinformed opinion.

Answer (score -1):

As in:  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/embarrassing) adj. usage of **embarrassing**

> It's really embarrassing how many people misspell embarrassing.

As in this usage from the citation, punctuation is not necessary in your particular question. In general, nonessential information is set off with commas. Essential information does not require commas.